# How to show all running processes on Centos OS with php?

Tags: php, centos7

So, my php code looks like this:

```
exec('ps aux', $out);
```

Running that on Ubuntu gives me a webpage with all running processes (all users), but on Centos OS 7 it shows only the processes of the 'apache' user.
Is there any way I can fix that?

EDIT:
**Any way**, I'm running it on a VM, it's just a school project.

sample output:

```
apache 8758 0.0.0.1 33052 7308 ? S S 03:50 0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd - DFOREGROUND
apache 1421 0.0.0.2 5128 2780 ? R 15:24 0:00 ps aux
```

Comment: I know from experience that Centos's apache package sets itself up correctly, in that it creates a separate user which is subject to the OS's restrictions. However, it sounds like Ubuntu is running apache as root, which is super not good and the reason you can see all the processes running on the system.

Comment: Thanks! So, can I run apache as root on Centos? It's just school stuff, we do not care about security. My teacher wants to see these processes on a web page, he doesn't care about the way we do it.
Do I have to add the 'apache' user to 'root' group?

Comment: Both systems run apache as root, apache will then drop privileges and use a non privileged user. If nothing extra is set security wise ps aux will list all processes. You don't need to be root to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on a lot of stuff on the server side.

More than likely what is happening is that your host is isolating your apache instances using CPU groups or similar. I would ask your host or the system admin why this is not working, but more than likely they'll just tell you they won't allow it. Allowing that sort of thing can have serious security implications.

Comment: I'm running on a VM, do you know how to allow it?

Comment: You'll provably need to check if selinux is enabled and if systemd  is forcing isolation on Apache.

Comment: Thank You! Disabled selinux now it's working as expected.